# Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that verify: $z^3=(-1-i)^4\cdot\overline{z}$ and $Im(z) \ge 0$ simultaneously

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that simultaneously verify:

$z^3=(-1-i)^4\cdot\overline{z}$

$Im(z) \ge 0$

I've already worked out the first part to be

$a^3-3ab^2+4a+i(3a^2b-b^3-4b)=0$

And that second part is $b \ge 0$

Comment: $$a(a^2-3b^2+4)=0$$ and $$b(3a^2-b^2-4)=0$$  can you solve the simultaneous equations in $a^2,b^2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ where $r\ge0, t$ is real

$$r^3(\cos3t+i\sin3t)=-4r(\cos t-i\sin t)$$

Taking modulus, $$r^3=4r\implies r=0,2\text{ as } r\ge0$$

If $r\ne0,$  $$-4=r^2(\cos4t+i\sin4t)=2^2(\cos4t+i\sin4t)$$

$$\implies\cos4t+i\sin4t=-1\iff\cos4t=-1\iff4t=(2n+1)\pi$$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies t=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}4$ where $0\le n\le3$

As $\sin t\ge0,0\le t\le\pi$

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that kind of resolution. Is it possible to solve this problem another way?

Comment: It should be $0 \le n \le 3$

Comment: @jjagmath, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$(1+i)^2 = 2i$ and hence $(1+i)^4 = -4$

So the equation is $z^3 = -4\overline{z}$

Taking modulus both sides we get $|z|^3 = 4|\overline{z}| =4 |z|$ from which we get $z=0$ or $|z|=2$ so that $z\overline{z}=4$ or $\overline{z}=\dfrac{4}{z}$

Substitute in original equation to obtain $z^4=-16 =16i^2$ so that $z^2=4i$ or $z^2=-4i$

that is $z^2 = 2(1+i)^2$ or $z^2 = 2(1-i)^2$

With the constraint $\Im(z) \ge 0$, we get $z=0$ or $z=\sqrt 2\left(i \pm 1 \right)$ as solutions

Comment: From $z^4=16i^2$ you get $z^2=\pm 4 i$, not $\pm 2i$

Comment: Thank you @jjagmath, will edit

Answer (score 0):

Since $\overline{z}^3 =-4z$ we have $$z^9 = 256z\;\;\;(*)$$

So $z_1=0$ and \begin{align}z^8&=256\\
\implies z^4 &=\pm 16\\\implies z^2 &=\pm 4 \wedge z^2 = \pm 4i = \pm 2(1+i)^2\\...\end{align}

Be carefull, not all solution $(*)$ are solution to OP.